# How to make hybrid blazor NET MAUI installed on Android use *.razor files from a remote server

Tags: blazor, maui

What I need to do to make a blazor hybrid app installed on Android work with a remote blazor components. Let say the UI runs on Android but server logic runs on Windows. The hybrid blazor app created with Visual Studio 2022 Preview can be installed on Android but then everything runs there (UI + blazor components). So how do we separate these parts actually? (so that BlazorWebView runs on Android but *.razor files, wwwroot folder,... remain on Windows)

Comment: If you don't want to run Blazor on Android, you don't need `BlazorWebView`, you can use some normal `WebView` and point that to your server URL. Or use browser on Android.

Comment: Thanks, that would definitely work. I don't see much sense in using hybrid blazor then while MS talks so much about it. One can develop normal NET MAUI apps and use whatever is available (REST, web services...) to get data from server

Comment: Because you can run it offline... Razor views are compiled, so  I don't think you can download them from a remote source, without updating your app binaries..